# issue:Null Pointer Exception In Android

Tags: java, android, function, nullpointerexception

i am a new android Developer,
i wrote one thread class,and i call the thread class when i click a button from another class but throw null pointer exception ,the class call define public this is my code,
Class A;

```
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    ClassB b=new ClassB();
    b.runalarm();
  }
```

Class B;

```
public void runalarm() 
{
SimpleThread my=new SimpleThread("myclass");
my.start();

}

class  SimpleThread extends Thread 
{
    private static final int None = 0;

    public SimpleThread(String str) 
    {
    super(str);
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
               boolean loop=true;
               DatabaseHelper1 dbHelper1=new DatabaseHelper1(getApplicationContext());
}
```

please solve my problem in advance

Comment: You should also attache your complete stack trace. I suspect it has something to do with `SimpleThread _my=new SimpleThread("myclass");` (initializing `_my`) and `my.start();` (invoking `my`), but cannot be sure without a stack trace and/or more code.

Comment: thanks for ur response,now i edit my code please help me

Comment: Please attach your [stack trace](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) as well.

Comment: Still not sufficiant. The code fragment looks NPE-safe. Could be inside the getApplicationContext method, inside the DatabaseHelper1 constructor or outside the fragment you've shown use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this...

```
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    ClassB b = new ClassB();

    ClassB.SimpleThread sx = b.new SimpleThread();

    sx.start();
  }
```